# What is correct pattern to create item with several options

Tags: checkboxes, material-design, google-materials-design

I'm developing a web app using angular and material design. At this moment, when I'm creating a new role I enter name and description of the role and role is created. After discussion with colleagues, we decided that we cannot create a role without adding at least one permission. What is the correct pattern to add permission in role-creation form?

Current role creation form:

[image]

Role permission's form:

[image]

Any ideas how I can integrate role creation form with role permission form?

Comment: Is it nesscary to create a role in the Side nav layer panel?

Comment: Kinda. We want to have consistency in the app. Other suggestions is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a material card in the "create role" section which can be used to manage permissions regarding that particular role.

Another suggestion is that your side nav layer should be on top of the page as an overlay.

Here is the wireframe of the concept explained above

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe I understood your suggestion and will try to implement this example in my app. Another question, what software you are using to create this sketch?

Comment: @ArminasGrigonis https://balsamiq.com/